# How to make a plot of generalized beta distribution?

Tags: r, plot, beta

I am trying to plot the beta-gumbel distribution using R(software) by the following,
The genreal idea is that, in the pdf of  beta distribution, instead of plugging in x, we use the cdf of gumbel instead. But I couldn't get the right plot.

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, length=100)
Fx = pgumbel(x,loc=0,scale=1)
y = dbeta(Fx,shape1=0.5,shape2=0.5)
plot(x, y, type="l", lty=2, xlab="x value", ylab="Density",ylim=c(0,1))
```

Comment: Let us know what package(s) you're using.

Comment: I didn't install any outside packages

Comment: Where is `pgumbel` coming from?

Comment: It's just a function embedded in R which calculate the cdf of gumbel, try ?pgumbel in R for the help file.

Comment: There are `pgumbel` functions in the packages **gumbel** and **ordinal** at least, and you would definitely have had to download and install those.

Comment: My bad! On my R, it says VGAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you when you say that you didn't use any add-on packages: `pgumbel()` is not in base R. `library("sos"); findFn("pgumbel")` finds it in a variety of places, I used the `evd` package.

There are a couple of small issues here.

```
library("evd")
```

The main thing is that you want `length=100` rather than `by=100` (which gives you a single-element `x` vector):

```
x <- seq(-3, 3, length=100)
```

The actual computations are OK:

```
Fx = pgumbel(x,loc=0,scale=1)
y = dbeta(Fx,shape1=0.5,shape2=0.5)
```

You need to change `ylim` to be able to see what's going on.  However, I also think you need to do something to account for the differential `dx` in order to get a proper density function (that's more of a StackExchange than a StackOverflow question though).

```
par(las=1,bty="l")  ## my personal preferences
plot(x, y, type="l", lty=2, xlab="x value", ylab="Density",ylim=c(0,40))
```

Comment: I tried several times and the plot does not look right... So I just typed in the whole formula and it worked.