# Plot beta distribution in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, probability-density, beta-distribution

Using the dataset `Lahman::Batting` I've estimated parameters for the **beta distribution**. Now I want to **plot this empirically derived beta distribution onto the histogram that I estimated it from**.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(Lahman)

career <- Batting %>%
  filter(AB > 0) %>%
  anti_join(Pitching, by = "playerID") %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>%
  summarize(H = sum(H), AB = sum(AB)) %>%
  mutate(average = H / AB)
```

I can plot the distribution of RBI as:

```
career %>% 
  filter(AB > 500) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = average)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  geom_freqpoly(color = "red")
```

And obtain:

[image]

I know I can use `+ geom_freqpoly` to obtain:

[image]

But I want the smooth **beta distribution**. I can estimate beta parameters by:

```
career_filtered <- career %>%
    filter(AB >= 500)

m <- MASS::fitdistr(career_filtered$average, dbeta,
                    start = list(shape1 = 1, shape2 = 10))

alpha0 <- m$estimate[1] # parameter 1
beta0 <- m$estimate[2] # parameter 2
```

Now that I have parameters `alpha0` and `beta0`, how do I plot the beta distribution so that I obtain something like this:

[image]

This question is based on a post I'm reading [here](http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/).

Comment: Perhaps, you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744596/how-to-make-a-plot-of-generalized-beta-distribution) by @BenBolker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All code, including the code for the plots, can be found [here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/dgrtwo.github.com/blob/master/_R/2015-10-01-empirical_bayes_baseball.Rmd). The following code is used to get the requested plot:

```
ggplot(career_filtered) +
  geom_histogram(aes(average, y = ..density..), binwidth = .005) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dbeta(x, alpha0, beta0), color = "red",
                size = 1) +
  xlab("Batting average")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Florian--this works! I see you've also been through this post on empirical Bayes estimation. Pretty powerful and yet simple method...