# How to draw Beta distribution curves in R?

Tags: r

I need to create this graph in R

[image]

but I don't like to look like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645689/plot-beta-distribution-in-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```r
c2 <- curve(dbeta(x, 3,1))
plot(curve(dbeta(x, 91, 11)), col="red", type="l", xlab="x", ylab="Beta Density")
lines(c2$x, c2$y, col="blue")
legend("topleft", 
       c("Beta(91,11)", "Beta(3,1)"), 
       inset=.01, 
       lty=c(1,1), 
       col=c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]